# Normalizing variable names C/C++

Tags: c++, c, variables, gcc, normalization

I am currently working on a tool, that will compare two files and report its differences. I want to implement a feature that will compare two methods, and  report if they are identical (*while ignoring variable name changes* ). What i have thought of doing, is to Normalize all the variable names to (x0,x1 ..) or something similiar. Then sort the methods ( Alphabetically? ) so that the order is the same. Grap their checksums and then compare the two.

My question:

How do i normalize variable names in a C / C++ file? 
or
Do you have any other ideas as to how i could implement the feature?

Regards

Comment: please, tell us how do you parse the source...

Comment: Yes, just identifying which variable use corresponds to which variable declaration is far from trivial.

Comment: You can map 'tokens' (variable names) to interned forms, as described above, according to a stable repeatable ordering.

Comment: Have a look at the algorithms [CPD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.2.5/cpd.html) has used over the years. It currently uses [Karp-Rabin](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads//HTML/karpRabin.html).

Comment: look here http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?reload=true&arnumber=6421180
As I remember LCS can be used somehow

Comment: maybe graphs & hashtables can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map 'tokens' (variable names) to an 'interned form', as described above, if you can come up with a repeatable & stable ordering.

This doesn't attempt to understand *how* the tokens resolve, merely that they are present in the same pattern in two source-files. "Tokens" would be everything other than C/C++ reserved words, no serious parsing/ lexing necessary.

Once you have done that you can convert comments & whitespace to a canonical form.

This wouldn't mostly be of utility to me, but I believe it would achieve a 99.9% or better stab at the problem -- it's conceivable that it could be fooled, but practically not very likely.

Of course, if we have macros those have to handled too..  maybe you can run the C pre-processor on them to fulfill that, if that's a requirement?

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Surely this is not about normalizing the names, but about figuring out if the two methods do the same thing to the same things within a class. Which means parsing the source code and building some sort of data structure [probably a "tree"] from that. Once you have the tree, the names as such will become meaningless. You may need to track for example what OFFSET into a class member variables are referring to, and which virtual functions within a class.

I don't believe this is at all trivial (unless you restrict the code to a small subset of C++ code), since there are so many different ways to make something do the same thing, and just subtle difference will throw off anything by the most sophisticated of tools. E.g.

```
class A
{
   private:
     int arr[10];
     ...
   public:
     int sum()
     {
        int r = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            r += arr[i];
        return r;
     }
}


class B
{
   private:
     int arr[10];
     ...
   public:
     int sum()
     {
        int r = 0;
        int *p = arr;
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            r += *p++;
        return r;
     }
     .... 
}
```

These two functions do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the temporary tree representation gcc generates during compilation, gcc has a command-line-switch to preserve temporary files:

```
gcc -save-temps <file>
```

This code is somewhat simplified and names are unified. The problem is to identify the differences in the original file.
Do not use Optimization!